# running cake console on mediatemple

Tags: cakephp, console

I am trying to run the cakephp2.0 console on mediatemple.

I did an install of the latest version of cakephp2.0, uploaded it to my server and got everything hooked up and running.

Then i SSHed into my server ( on mediatemple ) and navigated to the Console folder in my app then did

```
/html/app/Console$ cake bake
```

and got a 'command not found' error.. ok so then i tried the command

```
/html/app/Console$ php cake bake
```

which ran, but gave me this...

```
LIB=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P) && LIB=$LIB/$(basename -- "$0")

while [ -h "$LIB" ]; do
    DIR=$(dirname -- "$LIB")
    SYM=$(readlink "$LIB")
    LIB=$(cd "$DIR" && cd $(dirname -- "$SYM") && pwd)/$(basename -- "$SYM")
done

LIB=$(dirname -- "$LIB")/
APP=`pwd`

exec php -q "$LIB"cake.php -working "$APP" "$@"

exit;
```

Did i do something wrong? or is there a bug in the console for cakephp2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do:

```
./cake bake
```